# Combining Hard Drives

Tags: 12.04, windows-7

Ok so I have 3 hard drives in my machine, 1 that has Ubuntu 12.04 installed on it, one with Windows 7 and the last one has Unallocated space. The Windows 7 drive is almost full and I was wondering how can I extend my Win7 drive using Ubuntu? So that I have 2 Drives using Windows 7 and 1 drive using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend moving your personal folders and, if applicable, your music files to the new drive.  Format it with 4096K cluster sizes for best performance and go with NTFS.

for me, it's my downloads, music and video folders that are huge.  I run SSD's for my operating system, and redirect all downloads to the HDD, which is also where I store my music (I added music, downloads, and a video folder to my libraries).

Ubuntu doesn't seem to have a problem working with NTFS, and FAT32 is just bad.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Don't extend, use GParted to format the unallocated space on the third drive as a NTFS partition. This will enable Windows to see it. You can also use it in Linux as it pops up in the file manager as a volume you can mount.

I use ENCFS to create a directory on the NTFS partition to create a folder that will be encrypted so you can pump your Linux data onto it as well. Win O/S is not a O/S that easily extends drive space. A second drive is your best option.

Comment: ok i changed it to the NTFS

Comment: Then format it, or boot into windows and format it, either way is good. Note the size of the hard disk you are formatting to ensure its the right drive you are formatting :)